# UTF-8 characters messed up HTML tags in JSP in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, utf-8

In Spring mvc while displaying UTF-8 characters, the jsp is getting messed up. While debugging found that the http response itself contains the jsp content with some missing HTML tags. The UTF-8 contents are coming fine but the page is breaking some where else. The issue is inconsistent. I mean the page breaks in different place in different time. But the UTF contents are fine. Tried with all workaround but no result. 
Is there any problem in either spring side or container side?

Comment: Can you supply (a snippet of) your code and observations?

Comment: <table>
<tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="eventDetChkbox" value="userFirstName:神互相對待"></td><td>User First Name</td><td>神互相對待</td>
 <td><a class="search-icon" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick='javascript:sendSearchQuery("First Name神:互相對待")'></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><a class="search-icon" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick='javascript:sendSearc <td><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled"></td><td>Status Reason</td><td>  </td>
 <td></td>
</tr></table>

Comment: This is the response I observe in Response inside Filter. The first row contains UTF chars and the content is fine, But in 2nd row it breaks at 'javascript:sendSearc. Becoz of incomplete of the function next html tag/contents are missing in page.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the reason. We had some problem with the custom security filter where it was trying to convert the String into byte arrays and it was getting overflow for these UTF-8 characters.